# How to display a pptx file from server(API) in modal pop-up in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, httprequest, modalpopup

I have an API which allows me to download .pptx file. So, I am writing a Http get request with content type `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation` and response type- text.

However I am getting an error for `JSON.parse()`--- So, not able to download file.

Below is the code for reference:

service.ts:

```
getPPTs(){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        responseType : 'text',
        Accept : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
        observe : 'response'
      })
    };
    return this.http.get(environment.resourceUrl, httpOptions); 
  }
```

Also, I want to display `.pptx` file content in modal pop-up.

Can anybody suggest any solution?

Comment: Can you post the exact error? as a text?

Comment: Refused to display 'PPTLink' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: and  If I try to display local pptx file in iframe, the file gets downloaded and is never displayed in iframe.

Comment: Try to change `responseType : 'text'` with `responseType : 'blob'`, and check if it helps

Comment: Also tried with responseType: 'blob'. It also gives error like `error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token P in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at XMLHtt…, text: "PK!�2�C�u...`

Comment: Thanks @PrashantPimpale! Removing `httpOptions` and just adding `responseType:'blob'` worked upto downloading ppt. So, it worked partially. Now I want to display that ppt in a modal pop-up.

Comment: Glad it helped!